# Clever Cloud (S3 Bucket) can't serve compressed gzip files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gzip, clever-cloud

I'm using Clever Cloud with static hosting and I want to serve compressed files.
I used gzipper to generate gzipped files

```
"compress:gzip": "gzipper compress ./dist/apps/site ./dist/apps/site "
```

The dist folder contains both normal and compressed files, I tried to get into the S3 bucket config with the CLI and added Content-Length as an allowed header in the CORS configuration but that doesn't seem to work

CORS config :

```
<CORSConfiguration>
  <CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>console.clever-cloud.com</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>Content-Length</AllowedHeader>
    <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
  </CORSRule>
  <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>    
        <AllowedHeader>Content-Length</AllowedHeader>
  </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Comment: You should add URLs of your content (if public) to help investigate. The problem is too vague right now.

Comment: Can you provide the CORS configuration you applied on your bucket ?

Comment: @GaëlReyrol I edited initial message with CORS config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should expose the header `Content-Length` instead of allowing it. You should also expose `Content-Encoding` to tell the client that the server is sending a *gzipped* response.

- `AllowedHeader` is for request headers.
- `ExposeHeader` is for
  response headers.